# Android java NullPointerException Error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set a button onClick it goes to another page ,its simple still i get this error:

**java.lang.NullPointerException**

Here is my code :

**MainLogin.java :**

```
public class MainLogin extends Activity {

    Button AdminB,UserB;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_login);

        AdminB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdmin);
        UserB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnUser);
        //When i click on this button it gives me the error
        AdminB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**LoginActivity :**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Register Screen
      /*  btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });*/
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidsupervision"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- SplashScreen Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreen"
            android:label="Login Account" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <!-- UserLogin Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Login Account" >
        </activity>

         <!-- AdminLogin Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainLogin"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Register Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="Register New Account" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Allow to connect with internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

i have a SplashScreen --GoesTO--> MainLogin --GoesTO--> Ohter 2 pages

I'm so confused need help .

Here is a full Log :

```
05-12 20:13:00.881: W/dalvikvm(1372): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidsupervision/com.example.androidsupervision.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at com.example.androidsupervision.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:99)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-12 20:13:01.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):     ... 11 more
```

user_login.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <!-- Header Starts -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" >

            <!-- Logo Start -->

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/header_1" />
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Header Ends -->


        <!-- Footer Start -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Place footer next to header to set z-index property to minus value -->
        <!-- Footer Ends -->


        <!-- Login Form -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <!-- Email Label -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <!-- Password Label -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:password="true" />
            <!-- Error message -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_error"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textColor="#e30000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <!-- Login button -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Login" />
            <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Login Form Ends -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

main_login :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <!-- Header Starts -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" >

            <!-- Logo Start -->

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/header_1" />
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Header Ends -->


        <!-- Footer Start -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Place footer next to header to set z-index property to minus value -->
        <!-- Footer Ends -->


        <!-- Login Form -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <!-- Email Label -->
            <!-- Password Label -->
            <!-- Error message -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_error"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textColor="#e30000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <!-- Login button -->
            <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Login Form Ends -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdmin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:text="Administrateur" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnUser"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnAdmin"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Superviseur" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you share your error log

Comment: Please post the Logcat..

Comment: What is Line no 99 in LoginActivity ???

Comment: btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...
i Commented it

Comment: @user3629616 post your `user_login.xml`

Comment: That's magical when i comment that 99 ligne it works perfectly ,THANKS

Comment: @user3629616 no magic involved. the button is null not initialized properly and to confirm post the xml layout

Comment: @Lal it's a comment i cant mark it

Comment: @Raghunandan can you explain more please ?

Comment: @user3629616 can you post `user_login.xml` pls to explain more

Comment: please upvote my comment..

Comment: i posted both xml files

Comment: @user3629616 i posted an answer. i guess its clear or you want more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `btnLinkToRegister` is null.

```
btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
```

There is no `Button` with the id `btnLinkToRegisterScreen` in `user_login.xml`.

When you have this

```
btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Calling `setOnClickListener` when `btnLinkToRegister` is null leading to `NUllPointerException`

Comment: @user3629616 Your welcome. its `btnLogin` that you should use

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
public class MainLogin extends Activity {

    Button AdminB,UserB;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_login);

        AdminB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdmin);
        UserB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnUser);
        //When i click on this button it gives me the error
        AdminB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainLogin.this,
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: NPE is @ loginactivity. What is the problem in the one you just posted??

Answer (score -1):

on the onClick part of the button, use

```
AdminB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainLogin.this,
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
```